# Trilok is "three worlds" but what is Go Lok

Tags: vishnu, krishna

In Shri Krishna serial, Lord Krishna and Radha are in Go Lok, while Lord Krishna's avatar is on Earth.

What is translation of Go Lok? I know Trilok is "three worlds"

Please clarify.

Comment: Go-Loka is the abode of Lord Krishna where He stays eternally. His pastimes are temporarily manifested on earth(in vrindavan,dwarka etc). But He performs innumerable pastimes eternally in His abode;Go-loka or Goloka-Vrindavan. You can read more about Go-loka in 1st few chapters of Brahma-Vaivarta Puran.

Comment: "go" has innumerable meaning, one of them being cow. Since Krishna was a cow herder in his *avatara* on Earth, His abode is called *go-loka*. The world of cows. see. http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?beginning=0+&tinput=+go&trans=Translate

Comment: Again best answer given by Brahmakumaris,
Trilok are the three worlds .
Lowest being the world we live in , which souls enter to perform actions , where karmic accounts are made . Here souls are present with bodies made of matter . This is the lokik world. Above that is the subtle region , the angelic region , where souls have bodies made of light. This is the Alokis region.
Above that or can say beyond this universe , beyond matter , there is the soul world , which is also call Brahmand , which is the place of residence of all souls including The Father soul , Shiv. This region is called Parl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lord Krishna's own abode in the eternal spiritual world above this material world is called *goloka* (*go* -- cow; *loka* -- world, planet), meaning literally "cow-world".

There are many cows there and Lord Krishna enjoys his eternal pastimes there as a cowherd with gopas (cowherds) and gopis (cowherd girls), among which the most prominent gopi is Sri Radha, Lord Krishna's the most beloved.
The position of *goloka* can be nicely seen from the Lord Brahma's prayers offered in glorification to Lord Krishna in the Brahma-samhita 5.43: 
http://www.vedabase.com/en/bs/5/43

> "Lowest of all is located Devī-dhāma [mundane world], next above it is
>   Maheśa-dhāma [abode of Maheśa]; above Maheśa-dhāma is placed
>   Hari-dhāma [abode of Hari] and above them all is located Kṛṣṇa's own
>   realm named **Goloka**. I adore the primeval Lord Govinda, who has
>   allotted their respective authorities to the rulers of those graded
>   realms."

The entire spiritual world called Vaikuntha, which is above this material world called the Devī-dhāma "mundane world", is eternal and it is made of spiritual nature, namely it is not material. The material world where we live will be destroyed because it's a temporary place of death and destruction. Goloka is the highest planet in the spiritual world, and is eternal place of liberation (moksha) and immortality, ie the state of existence without destruction, death and *samsara* (repeated births and deaths).
Lord Krishna's own abode Goloka is not a material planet!

Answer (score 6):

Besides three worlds (Swarga Loka, Bhuloka, Patal Loka), many other Loka exists where various gods and deities reside. Like, Brahmaloka (abode of Lord Brahma), Vaikuntha (abode of Lord Vishnu), Kailash (abode of Lord Shiva), Suryaloka (abode of Son god), Chandraloka (abode of Moon god) and many more. Similarily, **Goloka is the abode where Lord Krishna live with Devi Radha and many celestial cows**.

For explanation, you make take a look at [SB 10.27.1](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/27/1).

> govardhane dhṛte śaile
>
> āsārād rakṣite vraje
>
> **go-lokād** āvrajat kṛṣṇaṁ
>
> surabhiḥ śakra eva ca
>
> After Kṛṣṇa had lifted Govardhana Hill and thus protected the inhabitants of Vraja from the terrible rainfall, **Surabhi, the mother of the cows, came from her planet** to see Kṛṣṇa. She was accompanied by Indra.

Answer (score 0):

Word 'Go' has multiple meanings. Here is a couplet: 
गो गोविन्द दिक्पाल दिक्, स्वर्ग वज्र खग छंद 
गो धर गो तरु गो किरण गो गोपाल गोविन्द
Which means, 'Go' means Krishna, Dikpala (Protectors of Directions), Directions, Heaven, Vajra (Mythological weapon of Indra made out of bones donated by Dadhichi), Bird, Meter, Earth, Tree, and Sunray

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! Nice answer.pls. add sources for the couplet you have provided in the answer.On this site we have to write answers with citing from authentic Hindu scriptures like Puranas ,Bhagvat Gita etc.